# Update Inventory and prices in Magento using a CSV

Tags: import, csv, import-products

We would like to update inventory quantities and prices in our Magento store from our ERP system.

We can generate CSV file in our ERP to be imported into Magento.

We need CSV file format layout.

Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento StackExchange. Could you explain a little bit more your question? Something like, what version of Magento are you using, what ERP, and any other detail you think can help the community to answer your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a cron job (every day at 2h00 for example) that reads your CSV file and updates your product info (ex: qty and price) accordingly.